# Laravel integrate with Instagram API after October 2019

Tags: laravel, instagram

Since Facebook updated their policy and forced developer to use Instagram Basic Display API:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/

How do I integrate Laravel with Instagram API?
I research around and all tutorial is about https://socialiteproviders.netlify.com/providers/instagram.html and it had been deprecated.

What I am going to do:

1. User login to our campaign
2. Check user had uploaded a photo with certain hashtag
3. If yes, user is valid to join our campaign

Run out of idea and create a question here. Thanks anyhow has idea to do it.

Comment: It seems you can't grab the email address at all from this API which makes using it for login impossible for me.

Also, this according to the new Facebook developer panel...

Note that Basic Display is not an authentication tool. Data returned by the API cannot be used to authenticate your app users or log them into your app. If your app uses API data to authenticate users, it will be rejected during App Review. If you need an authentication solution, use Facebook Login instead.

Yeah, it sounds like "Login with Instagram" is officially dead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ah, at the end, follow the guideline from Facebook docs:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started

Here is the solution in case anyone needed it:

1. Install guzzle

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

2. Add this in .env

```
INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID=
INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_SECRET=
INSTAGRAM_REDIRECT_URI=https://yourdomainname.com/login/instagram/callback
```

3. Add this in routes/web.php

```
Route::get('login/instagram',
 'Auth\LoginController@redirectToInstagramProvider')->name('instagram.login');

Route::get('login/instagram/callback', 'Auth\LoginController@instagramProviderCallback')->name('instagram.login.callback');
```

4. Add this in config/services.php

```
'instagram' => [  
     'client_id' => env('INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID'),  
     'client_secret' => env('INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_SECRET'),  
     'redirect' => env('INSTAGRAM_REDIRECT_URI'),  
],
```

5. Add this in Auth/LoginController.php

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

public function redirectToInstagramProvider()
{
    $appId = config('services.instagram.client_id');
    $redirectUri = urlencode(config('services.instagram.redirect'));
    return redirect()->to("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?app_id={$appId}&redirect_uri={$redirectUri}&scope=user_profile,user_media&response_type=code");
}

public function instagramProviderCallback(Request $request)
{
    $code = $request->code;
    if (empty($code)) return redirect()->route('home')->with('error', 'Failed to login with Instagram.');

    $appId = config('services.instagram.client_id');
    $secret = config('services.instagram.client_secret');
    $redirectUri = config('services.instagram.redirect');

    $client = new Client();

    // Get access token
    $response = $client->request('POST', 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token', [
        'form_params' => [
            'app_id' => $appId,
            'app_secret' => $secret,
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
            'redirect_uri' => $redirectUri,
            'code' => $code,
        ]
    ]);

    if ($response->getStatusCode() != 200) {
        return redirect()->route('home')->with('error', 'Unauthorized login to Instagram.');
    }

    $content = $response->getBody()->getContents();
    $content = json_decode($content);

    $accessToken = $content->access_token;
    $userId = $content->user_id;

    // Get user info
    $response = $client->request('GET', "https://graph.instagram.com/me?fields=id,username,account_type&access_token={$accessToken}");

    $content = $response->getBody()->getContents();
    $oAuth = json_decode($content);

    // Get instagram user name 
    $username = $oAuth->username;

    // do your code here
}
```

Comment: hello. I tried to follow the fb docs and the code but it get me `"error_type": "OAuthException",
  "code": 400,
  "error_message": "Invalid platform app"`

Comment: @Vince hi, it's been awhile I didn't update this anymore but I found similar thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60258144/invalid-platform-app-error-using-instagram-basic-display-api hope it might helps