# "Invalid platform app" error using Instagram Basic Display API

Tags: php, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, instagram-graph-api

I am trying to use Instagram Basic display API but when I post the authorization code to get the access token I keep getting the following error

> {"error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message":
> "Invalid platform app"}

I am following all the steps mentioned here -> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started and Yes I am using the Instagram app ID and It's client secret which is in `Products -> Instagram -> Display` and following is the URL I am sending the request

"https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=".$app_id."&client_secret=".$app_secret."&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=".$redirecturi."&code=".$code,

Comment: Have you added your Instagram account to the tester section in the dashboard? And if you visit Instagram on the web are you definitely logged into that account and not another one?

Comment: Yes, I have added the tester account and when I  click the login button it takes me to [this](https://monosnap.com/file/78UcxIR2rQPMbre8IJpE4iMwUhRtBS) screen.

Yes, I am logged in with the same account on Instagram.com which I added as a test account check [screenshot](https://monosnap.com/file/78UcxIR2rQPMbre8IJpE4iMwUhRtBS)

Comment: Even if I remove all the parameters from the request It sends the same error nothing like "Client ID is missing etc."

Comment: How did you get the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you exchange the code you need to use a POST request.

From the looks of your url, you've formed it as a GET request with all the parameters as part of the url rather than as form data. Try sending the parameters as part of the post body instead

Comment: Here is the example code I am using
`$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "client_id:{client_id}",
    "client_secret:{client_secret}",
    "grant_type: authorization_code",
    "redirect_uri: {redirect_url}",
    "code: {code}"
 ),
));`

Comment: I tried adding in URL and in the form data as well nothing works

Comment: You’re sending it as a http header there, not the body

Comment: Thank you so very much TommyBS, I was pulling my hair out from one day, I was trying to send the request by the postman very new to it. BTW Thanks again for looking into this

Comment: If anyone having same issue and wondering how to do it with postman see the [screenshot](https://monosnap.com/file/eyAjjZEVoFwbqfFInsrr4szcqVx85N) and the example code is below.

Comment: @DanishAliMalik you are my hero. Thanks for the screenshot.  The problem for me is that I am a postman noob.

Comment: @tohidmahmoudvand perhaps you should raise a new question with your own code - especially if you were the downvoter

Answer (score 50):

I ran into this same issue. Problem was I was using the Facebook App ID and App Secret instead of the Instagram App ID & App Secret. You must go to the "Instagram Basic Display" section on the Facebook developers site then scroll down until you find the Instagram App ID & Secret.

Comment: I'm using this too, because "Instagram Basic Display" no longer exists and now is called "Instagram Graph API". So how to find the ID & secret?

Comment: @hotdogsoup.nl You probably already figured this out, but that is incorrect. Both exist. You need to select the "Consumer" app type in developers.facebook.com to create an app with Basic Display. The higher option ("Developer"?) doesn't have Basic Display and only has Graph

Answer (score 9):

If you are using Postman, do remember it's a POST request. Use form data

[image]

Comment: I was simply adding params for  a POST request. Changed back to "form-data" under Body

Answer (score 3):

Working example code:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('client_id' => '{client_id}','client_secret' => '{client_secret}','grant_type' => 'authorization_code','redirect_uri' => '{redirect_uri}','code' => '{code}'),
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------780367731654051340650991"
  ),
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
print_r($response);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got this error for the below reason.

If any case, App Id and Secret Key are blank then this type of error is generated. so we can first test first that that app id and secret key must be the correct one. I know that this is a very normal thing that we can notice easily. But sometimes, we can not notice some simple things.